# How to show that this integral is greater than the other integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

How can we show that
$$\int_{x-b}^{x-a}e^{-t^2}dt > \int_{x+a}^{x+b}e^{-t^2}dt$$ for $x>0$, $0 < a < b$?

EDIT:
I can show the case for when $x-b > 0$. First, $e^{-t^2}$ is monotonically decreasing on the range $t>0$ since the derivative $-2te^{-t^2} < 0$ on that range. Now, by the Extreme value theorem, $e^{-t^2}$ attains a minimum at $t=x-a$ in the range $[x-b, x-a$]. Hence,
$$
\int_{x-b}^{x-a}e^{-t^2}dt > \int_{x-b}^{x-a}e^{-(x-a)^2}dt = (b-a)e^{-(x-a)^2}
\tag{1}
$$. For similar reasons, we can show that
$$\int_{x+a}^{x+b}e^{-t^2}dt < \int_{x+a}^{x+b}e^{-(x+a)^2}dt = (b-a)e^{-(x+a)^2}\tag{2}
$$
We can show that $(b-a)e^{-(x-a)^2} > (b-a)e^{-(x+a)^2}$ by demonstrating that $\frac{(b-a)e^{-(x-a)^2}}{(b-a)e^{-(x+a)^2}} > 1$. We have
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{(b-a)e^{-(x-a)^2}}{(b-a)e^{-(x+a)^2}} &= \frac{e^{-(x-a)^2}}{e^{-(x+a)^2}}\\
&=\frac{e^{2ax}}{e^{-2ax}}\\
&=e^{2ax-(-2ax)}\\
&=e^{4ax} > 1
\end{split}
$$
for $x>0$ and $a>0$. Therefore, from (1) and (2) $\Rightarrow \int_{x-b}^{x-a}e^{-t^2}dt > \int_{x+a}^{x+b}e^{-t^2}dt$

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Most straightforward thing to do is solving the given integrals, then compare both expressions with the conditions that are given.

Comment: @Kemit4 this integral doesn't have a closed-form solution

Comment: @TheSilverDoe since it doesn't have a closed-form solution, I'm not too sure how to proceed, I was thinking that I can show the function is decreasing on t>0 interval but that won't cover all cases, as for x<b means I have to look into the other interval that is increasing

Comment: @Ivalin Ok, please edit your question by adding your attempts, so we can help you !

Comment: Can you show the case for $ x-b > 0$? Hint (which you already stated): Instead of $e^{-t^2}$, replace with $f(x)$ a decreasing function on the positive reals.  $\quad$ After that, how can we deal with the case of $ x-b < 0 $?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I've edited my question to add this case

Comment: @CalvinLin I've edited the question to add the case of $x-b > 0$. However, I'm not too sure why you want me to replace $f(x)$ with another function and what function that should be

Comment: Recreational Mathematics 

Comment: Thanks for showing your work! The reason why I encouraged switching to a more general function, is because 1/ it's  true for a larger class, and 2/ It allows you to get to the crux(EG closed form integral isn't important). $\quad$ In essence, your solution is showing that on intervals $I$ and $J$, $\min f(i) > \max f(j)$, so $\int_I > \int_J$. This is going to be true of any decreasing function. $\quad$ Unfortunately, with the even function, we no longer necessarily have $ \min f(i) \geq \max f(j)$. How can we deal with this situation? Is there a way to split intervals into different sections?

Comment: @HappieHappieHappie there was a small error in the integral bounds for $(1)$ which I have now fixed. The result is still correct

Comment: If you can't modify this approach, then perhaps try to come up with a different solution for the general decreasing function, and see if we can modify that to the even function (that is decreasing on the positive reals).

Comment: @CalvinLin I presume that you're suggesting splitting it into decreasing and increasing parts. However, I think there will be two more cases: $x-b<0<x-a$ and $x-b<x-a<0$?

Comment: Work through it and see what you get. I'd be happy to review your writeup. Your approach is different from the one I had in mind, so I don't know the details off the top of my head.

Comment: @CalvinLin I'm a bit unsure what you have in mind. Can you elaborate a bit further?

Comment: I'd add my solution afterwards. Just focus on pushing your version through.

Comment: @CalvinLin I've added the rest of my solution below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Here's an outline of a solution that dispenses with calculus as soon as possible.

1. Substitute $u = -t + x$ in the left-hand integral and $u = t - x$ in the right-hand integral, so that we are comparing two integrals over the same interval; we now want to show:
   $$\int_a^b e^{-(u - x)^2} du > \int_a^b e^{-(u + x)^2} du .$$
2. Observe that since $a < b$, to show the inequality it suffices to show that the corresponding inequality holds between the integrands, that is, that
   $$e^{-(u - x)^2} > e^{-(u + x)^2}$$
   for all $u$ in the interval $[a, b]$ of integration.

> 3. One way to establish the inequality in (2) is to multiply both sides by the reciprocal $e^{(u + x)^2}$ of its right-hand side, which is positive for all $u$ and so does not change the direction of the inequality. Simplify.

Comment: In the last part it suffices to apply the triangle inequality: $|u-x|< u+x.$ In this way we can replace $e^{-t^2}$ by any even function $f(t)$ decreasing for $t\ge 0.$

Comment: That is a very elegant solution, thanks

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Isn't the triangle inequality $|u-x| \leq u+x$?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can your idea be extended to the case where $0 \leq a < b$?

Comment: @Ivalin This was how I was approaching it. The idea is that if $f(x) < g(x)$, then the integrals will be too. In the $ X > b $ case (for decreasing functions), we could set $f(x - a-b) < f(x) $ and integrate from $X+a$ to $X+b$. This fails for $ X< b$ (due to the max at 0), BUT if we switch it to $ f( x - u ) > f(x+u)$ for $x, u > 0$ and integration from $u = a$ to $b$, we get the desired result.

Comment: If both $u$ and $x$ are positive there is no equality.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc right, I thought you were stating it in general but you were doing so for the problem

Comment: @CalvinLin Right, that's a neat approach

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding the rest of my solution here for completion.

First, we can show that
$$
\int_{x}^{x+\alpha} f(t)dt > \int_{x+\gamma}^{x+\gamma+\alpha} f(t) dt
$$
for $f(t)$ a monotonically decreasing function on $t \in [0; +\infty)$ such that $f(t) > 0$ on that range, $x \geq 0$ and $\alpha, \gamma > 0$.

Case I: $x+\gamma \geq x+\alpha$

By the Extreme value theorem, $f(t)$ attains a minimum at $x+\alpha$ in the range $[x; x+\alpha]$, hence:
$$
\int_{x}^{x+\alpha} f(t)dt > \alpha f(x+\alpha)
$$
Similarly, we can show that
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{x+\gamma}^{x+\gamma+\alpha}f(t)dt < \alpha f(x+\gamma)
\end{split}
$$
Since $f(t)$ is monotonically decreasing, $\alpha f(x+\gamma) \leq \alpha f(x+\alpha)$. Therefore, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{x}^{x+\alpha} f(t)dt > \alpha f(x+\alpha) &\geq \alpha f(x+\gamma) > \int_{x+\gamma}^{x+\gamma+\alpha}f(t)dt \\
\int_{x}^{x+\alpha} f(t)dt &> \int_{x+\gamma}^{x+\gamma+\alpha}f(t)dt\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Case II: $x+ \gamma < x + \alpha$. Note that $x+ \gamma +\alpha > x + \alpha$

Here we have
$$
\int_{x}^{x+\alpha}f(t)dt = \int_{x}^{x+\gamma} f(t)dt + \int_{x+\gamma}^{x+\alpha}f(t)dt
$$
Let $\int_{x+\gamma}^{x+\alpha}f(t)dt = k$. We can then write the above integral as
$$
\int_{x}^{x+\alpha}f(t)dt = k + \int_{x}^{x+\gamma} f(t)dt\tag{4}
$$
Similarly, we can show that
$$
\int_{x+\gamma}^{x+\gamma+\alpha}f(t)dt = k + \int_{x+\alpha}^{x+\gamma+\alpha}f(t)dt\tag{5}
$$
Using $(3)$ we can show that $\int_{x}^{x+\gamma}f(t)dt > \int_{x+\alpha}^{x+\gamma+\alpha}f(t)dt$.
Hence,
$$
k+\int_{x}^{x+\gamma}f(t)dt > k+\int_{x+\alpha}^{x+\gamma+\alpha}f(t)dt\tag{6}
$$
From $(4)$, $(5)$ and $(6) \Rightarrow$
$$
\int_{x}^{x+\alpha} f(t)dt > \int_{x+\gamma}^{x+\gamma+\alpha} f(t) dt\tag{7}
$$

Now, going back to the original problem. In the case of $x - b < 0 \leq x - a$ we have
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{x-b}^{x-a}e^{-t^2}dt &= \int_{x-b}^{0}e^{-t^2}dt + \int_{0}^{x-a}e^{-t^2}dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{b-x}e^{-t^2}dt + \int_{0}^{x-a}e^{-t^2}dt
\end{split}
$$
and
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{x+a}^{x+b} e^{-t^2}dt &= \int_{x+a}^{2x}e^{-t^2}dt + \int_{2x}^{x+b} e^{-t^2}dt
\end{split}
$$
Using $(3)$ we can show that
$$
\int_{0}^{x-a} e^{-t^2}dt > \int_{x+a}^{2x} e^{-t^2}dt\tag{8}
$$
Similarly, using $(7)$ we can show that
$$
\int_{0}^{b-x} e^{-t^2} dt > \int_{2x}^{x+b} e^{-t^2} dt\tag{9}
$$
Combining $(8)$ and $(9) \Rightarrow$
$$
\int_{x-b}^{x-a}e^{-t^2}dt > \int_{x+a}^{x+b} e^{-t^2}dt
$$

Lastly, we have the case of $x-b < x- a < 0$. Here, we have
$$
\int_{x-b}^{x-a}e^{-t^2}dt = \int_{a-x}^{b-x}e^{-t^2}dt\tag{10}
$$
because $e^{-t^2}$ is an even function. Directly applying $(7)$ here gives that
$\int_{a-x}^{b-x}e^{-t^2}dt > \int_{x+a}^{x+b}e^{-t^2}dt$. Therefore, that, combined with $(10)$ gives
$$
\int_{x-b}^{x-a}e^{-t^2}dt > \int_{x+a}^{x+b} e^{-t^2}dt
$$

Comment: I didn't check through the details, but yes breaking up into the $[0, x-a], $ and further intervals, we can (painfully) do the comparison.